# Can our orbit support a second planetary mass

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, physics, solar-system

If for a 'magic' Reason a second planetary mass of roughly equal proportions to earth appeared in the same orbit as earth. Is there any way that both masses could continue to orbit and remain in the habitable zone?

Comment: Is the extra planet moving at exactly the same speed as Earth and in the same direction? Because if it's not doing one or both of those, then either it, the Earth or both the planets will be gone very soon.

Comment: Also, the habitable zone of a star doesn't change based on the planets in the system.

Comment: @Snowshard - re: habitable zone: I'm pretty sure ChaosCenturian was asking whether the two planets would force one another out of the habitable zone of the star, not whether the zone itself would change.

Comment: They recently found a star with 4 planets in the Goldilocks zone, which they previously thought was impossible. So 2 is a piece of cake. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3587358/Synchronised-spinning-Family-four-planets-discovered-orbits-carefully-timed-keeps-stable.html

Answer (score 5):

In 1772, Joseph-Louis Lagrange published an "Essay on the three-body problem" in which he showed, inter alia, that two Earths orbiting the sun 60 degrees apart constitutes a stable configuration.

The distance between the two Earths would be about 149 million kilometers, or about 93 million miles.

Comment: I may be thinking about the wrong essay - but shouldn't the third mass be much smaller than the others? I doubt another "planetary mass" would be stable.

Answer (score 1):

If the planets can be effectively considered as two point masses, Langrage's considerations hold valid and it would be possible to have what you ask.

However, perturbation of the second or higher order, induced i.e. by mountain ranges or mass distribution inside the planets, would add small perturbations to the system leading, sooner or later, to at least one of the two to be kicked out of the orbit.

Comment: *Why* or *How* would these perturbations kick one of both planets out of orbit?

Comment: they would move the planet out of the "magic spot" at 60 degrees from the other, and from there the two planet would start a reciprocal dance ending up in either an impact or a kick...

Comment: Actually in simulations the orbit of one of the planets, likely the one of lesser mass, stays in the same circle but becomes erratic; most likely leading to a collision between the two planets. Many astrophysicists believe this is exactly how we ended up with a moon: That a Mars-mass second planet formed in the same range as Earth in the early solar system, at an L4 or L5 Lagrange point (Three such points can exist in the same orbit, forming an equilateral triangle); but became unstable and crashed into Earth; the molten debris (from both) coalesced into the Moon/Earth system.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T I think [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point#/media/File:Lagrangian_points_equipotential.jpg) is sufficient to explain. Notice how the gravitational curves all slope *away* from the Lagrange points in at least one direction. L4 and L5 are the "most" stable (as evidenced by the Trojan asteroids) but it's not a sure thing.

Comment: @Draco18s sufficient to explain *what*? Assuming the blue sphere is the earth and thus the yellow one is the sun, there's no Lagrangian point at the *magic spot of 60deg* that LDutch mentions in his comment...

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Uh, yes there are. They're helpfully labeled L4 and L5. `The L4 and L5 points lie at the third corners of the two equilateral triangles in the plane of orbit whose common base is the line between the centers of the two masses, such that the point lies behind (L5) or ahead (L4) of the smaller mass with regard to its orbit around the larger mass.` What's the angle of an equilateral triangle? 60 degrees.

Comment: @Draco18s please take a look at the same image you posted above. The image shows L1 and L2 on the axis from sun through earth, before and after earth respectively. It shows L4 and L5 at 30 deg from earth each on earths orbit around the sun and L3 at 180 deg from earth, aka on the other side of the sun. There ar **NO** Lagrange points at 60deg from earth on that image. || Please do not use graphics that you cannot correctly interpret for your own sake in any argument.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T you know how perspective projections works, yes? The image I linked to uses it. https://s9.postimg.org/xx4w8ujin/lagrange.png count the sections, there are 6, they are all of equal size, albeit skewed due to perspective. 360 / 6 = 60. Ergo each one must be 60 degrees around the circle. Also I meausred the angle in flat image space from Earth to L4, it's 45 degrees. To L5, 72 degrees. As these are meant to be identical angles, we can average those values (due to the skew) and get.... oh gosh, 58.5, really close to 60, within the acceptable error for pixel based measurement.

Comment: @Draco18s it seems to me that you're not reading what I am writing. I am not saying that the L3, L4 and L5 points are anything but 60deg spaced from each other. I am saying that there's no L-point spaced 60deg from Earth. Earth, the blue sphere on the frikkin image you link and relink. Please take time to relax, then reread.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T 60 degrees out from Earth would be either L4 or L5, per the definition of L4 and L5. Have a top-down image. With a protractor on top. https://s15.postimg.org/lt8z10nej/lagrange_60.png

Comment: @Draco18s I guess I am out then. I messed up circles. || Still, instead of having a productive discussion it seems you are just rubbing it in. What a waste of time..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59933/discussion-between-draco18s-and-dot-sp0t).